# Center text vertically

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

How can I vertically center some simple text in a normal `<div>`? I have markup like this:

```
<div style="height:200px;">
   <span style="display:inline; vertical-align:middle;">ABOUT</span>
<div>
```

It doesn't work under either Firefox or Internet Explorer. Why not?

Comment: It doesn't work under Chrome either. Because that's not how `vertical-align` works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align text vertically center in div with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[That's not what `vertical-align` does.](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/) You probably want `line-height`:

```
<div>
    <span style="line-height: 200px;">ABOUT</span>
</div>
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/GMmSJ/)

Answer (score 1):

I have found using a spacing element to the most reliable method of centering any element you know the height of (image, text). This will center an element in a container of any height.

***CSS:***

```
#outer {
    background: grey;
    height: 200px; /* any height */
}

#outer > div {
    height: 50%;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
}

#outer span {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<div id="outer">
    <div></div>
    <span>Example</span>
</div>
```

Comment: May as well use relative or absolute positioning in such cases.

Comment: Actually, with an absolutely positioned element inside a relatively positioned one, using, say, top:50%, your element will not be perfectly centered because you cannot subtract the element's own height. For dynamic vertical centering you need a negative padding or margin.

Comment: `top: 50%; margin-top: -(half height)`, actually.

Comment: Well I'll be darned: http://jsfiddle.net/MaxPRafferty/2VHBZ/13/
also, thanks for catching me using the full element height!